# Request for feedback: Couchdb setup with client replication (pouchdb) for multiple users/accounts

Tags: node.js, security, authentication, couchdb, pouchdb

Before jumping into development, I'd like to get feedback on a change I'm thinking of making, moving from mongo to couch.

Basically I've got a webapp which is used to help organize users activities (todolist, calendar, notes, journal).  It currently uses mongodb, but i'm thinking to move it to couch, mainly due to couches replication ability, and clientdb interaction (pouchdb).  I have a similar homegrown setup on the browser using localstorage, backed by mongo, but am looking for a more mature solution.

Due to how couchdb differs from mongodb, I'm thinking that each user should have their own couch db, and their documents being each of my app components.  Basically I have to move everything up a level with couch due to local db replication, and due to security.

I have 3 questions.

1) I assume that couch does not have document level security/authentication, correct?  (Hence me moving each user assets to their own database, good idea?)

2) My plan is have users login to the website, then my backend nodejs code authenticates them, and sends them down some auth/session token.  The javascript on the client then uses its local pouchdb data to set itself up, and also sends the replication request directly to the couchdb server (using the auth token it got from my server-side process).  They should only have access to their database, since I can do per database auth access (correct?)
What do you think of that setup?  It should work?

3) Regarding couchdb service providers, why do they vary so much on their couch version?  IE, happycouch, 1.6.1, iris 1.5, cloudant, 1.0.2?  And I also hear about couchdb 2.0 coming out soon...  I'd like to use cloudant, but 1.0.2 is so many versions back from a 1.6 or 1.5, if I'm not doing anything exotic, does it matter?

Bonus question :p  Continuing from the last question, do you know of any services that host node.js and have local instances of couchdb available?  I'd like to use my backend server code as a proxy, but not at the expense of another network hop.

Thank you very much for your feedback,
Paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Due to how couchdb differs from mongodb, I'm thinking that each user should have their own couch db

This is a CouchDB best practice. Good choice.

> I assume that couch does not have document level security/authentication, correct? (Hence me moving each user assets to their own database, good idea?)

You are correct: https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-authentication

> My plan is have users login to the website...

Yep. You can just pass the cookie headers straight through from Node.js to CouchDB, and it'll work fine. nano has some docs on how to do that: https://github.com/dscape/nano#using-cookie-authentication

> Regarding couchdb service providers, why do they vary so much on their couch version

The Couch community is one big happy fragmented family. :)

> I'd like to use cloudant, but 1.0.2 is so many versions back from a 1.6 or 1.5, if I'm not doing anything exotic, does it matter?

1.0.2 refers to when Cloudant forked CouchDB. They've added so many of their own features since then, that they're pretty much feature-equivalent by now.

The biggest difference between the various Couch implementation is in authentication. Everybody (Cloudant, CouchDB, Couchbase) does it differently.

Comment: Thanks for that feedback Nolan.  I'm going to check out using nano with Nodejs.  Can you make a recommendation on going with cloudant or couchdb (say from iris for example)?

Comment: I was not clear about client db access.  After authentication from my nodejs backend code, do you recommend still proxying though my nodejs instance for all client to couchdb activity (via express/nano) or to simply bootstrap client requests with some type of cookie/auth info and have them directly talk to the couchdb instance (bypassing my nodejs server).

Comment: It's pretty much 6 of one, half a dozen of the other. I would probably proxy it so I could have a bit more control over what parts of the CouchDB API my users have access to.

Comment: Good Point Nolan, That would also allow me to intelligently distribute requests to various couchdb service providers or locally for priority users.

Comment: Hey Nolan, got a bit sidetracked but now i'm back to this migration.  Quick question, I'll be using pouchdb (thank you very much for abstracting away that layer on the client ;) and on the backend, which do you recommend, couchdb or couchbase, to talk to my client pouchdb instances?

Comment: PouchDB is compatible with both, but our tests currently show better compatibility with CouchDB.

Comment: Thanks for that, I've decided to try to roll with Cloudant after reading lots about their bigcouch merge.  I see what you mean about variations of security handling, I'll let you know how it goes :)

Comment: So how did this go?